c# HttpWebRequest response string array object parsing error
I want to parse http request response into myDATA class. But gives me error
My codes under below. Im using also NEWtonsoft.Json
public class myDATA
{
        [JsonProperty("data1")]
        public string data1 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("data2")]
        public string data2 { get; set; }
}

string url = "https://www.domain/test.php";
HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = "key=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtLISANS.Text.ToString()) +
         "&hwid=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Genel.HWID().ToString());
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
httpWReq.Accept = "application/json";

using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
       stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();


var datas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myDATA>(responseString);
MessageBox.Show(datas.data1.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(datas.data2.ToString());`


RESPONSE JSON FROM WEB

[
    {
        "data1": "324234",
        "data2": "00331"
    }
]

Where is mistake ? dont shows data1 and data 2
I didnt find any solution. thanks for help.

if response like [], this is array or list, like List<myDATA>, change JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myDATA>(responseString) to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myDATA>>(responseString)

@wenming i did same

by the way, you should alternative HttpWebRequest to HttpClient, see this HttpWebRequest

you should print responseString to ensure that is json not html

var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "TEST2"));
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("hwid", "TEST2"));
var client = new HttpClient();
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, baseUrl) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc) };
var res = client.SendAsync(req);
var result = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();     but dont add variables

Console.WriteLine(responseString); check string is json formatter

@wenming i checked true returns [
{
"data1": "324234",
"data2": "00331"
}
]

@wenming can you write true sample ? with this variables ? i will try ty

var responseStr = "[ { \"data1\": \"324234\", \"data2\": \"00331\" } ] ";
var myDataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myDATA>>(responseStr);
Console.WriteLine(myDataList);
myDataList object can seserialize from responseStr

Why are you using the ancient HttpWebRequest anyway, why not the newer HttpClient?

@Charlieface worked ty

Try to handle the json as a list of several objects:
var datas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myDATA>>(responseString);
MessageBox.Show(datas[0].data1);
MessageBox.Show(datas[0].data2);


same  you can write sample working ?
